# How to change code T-25-4 into T-25-04 in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, converters

I have a data.frame in R. The first columns contain codes like T-25-4. I want to change it to T-25-04 and so on. So the last number should be in 2 digits

Example:

```
T-25-1
T-25-2
T-25-3
T-25-4
T-25-5
T-25-6
T-25-7
T-25-8
T-25-9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing first part of ycw's answer, but simpler with `mutate` and `gsub`:

```
library(tidyverse)
dt <- data_frame(Col = c("T-25-1", "T-25-2", "T-25-3", "T-25-4", "T-25-5",
                     "T-25-6", "T-25-7", "T-25-8", "T-25-9"))

dt %>%
  mutate(Col = gsub("(\\d)$", paste0("0", "\\1"), Col))
```

If last digit goes higher than 9 and you don't want to add 0:

```
dt %>%
  mutate(Col = ifelse(nchar(sub(".*-(\\d+)$", "\\1", Col)) < 2, # Check if last number is less than 10
                      sub("(\\d+)$", paste0("0", "\\1"), Col), # Add 0 in front if less than 10
                      Col))
```

Comment: Nice solution with `gsub` and regex, but if there are any rows with two digits number, such as `T-25-11`, this solution will lead to `T-25-101`. The output may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: Yup, added a conditional, not as nice looking.

Answer (score 1):

We can use functions from `tidyverse` and `stringr`. `df2` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

# Create example data frame
dt <- data_frame(Col = c("T-25-1", "T-25-2", "T-25-3", "T-25-4", "T-25-5",
                         "T-25-6", "T-25-7", "T-25-8", "T-25-9"))

# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  # Separate the original column to three columns
  separate(Col, into = c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")) %>%
  # Pad zero to Col3 until the width is 2
  mutate(Col3 = str_pad(Col3, width = 2, side= "left", pad = "0")) %>%
  # Combine all three columns separated by "-
  unite(Col, Col1:Col3, sep = "-")

# View the reuslts
dt2
# A tibble: 9 x 1
      Col
*   <chr>
1 T-25-01
2 T-25-02
3 T-25-03
4 T-25-04
5 T-25-05
6 T-25-06
7 T-25-07
8 T-25-08
9 T-25-09
```